# Gebrauch von 'so' in einem Beispiel

Tags: word-usage

Aus dem Grimms Märchen "Rotkäppchen":

> Mach dich auf, bevor es heiss wird, und wenn du hinauskommst, **so** geh hübsch sittsam und lauf nicht vom Wege ab, sonst fällst du und zerbrichst das Glas, und die Grossmutter hat nichts. Und wenn du in ihre Stube kommst, **so** vergiss nicht guten Morgen zu sagen und guck nicht erst in allen Ecken herum!

Das Wort 'so' verwirrt mich. Ändert es die Bedeutungen von den Sätze? Hätten sie es weglassen können?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Die Konstruktion

> **wenn..., so...**

ist gehoben bis veraltend und bedeutet dasselbe wie

> **wenn..., dann...**

Diese Bedeutung findet man unter 7b im entsprechenden [Duden-Eintrag](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/so_derartig_solch_genauso_etwa).

Genauso wie "dann" kann man auch "so" im entsprechenden Satz weglassen, ohne den Sinn desselben zu verändern.

Comment: Vielen dank für die Antwort!